# Query for getting record From table when primary key have special character

Tags: mysql

I am storing the ObjectID which was in byte as input and I am changing it into  String and then  saving it in id column of `varchar(255)` type. 
when I execute the select query I am able to see the Id value =

\\1c\\04\\9c\\44\\d5\\ee\\99\\44\\ad\\85\\94\\6a\\e9\\7a\\69\\70
(with double backslash)

I want to  get the record on the bases of this  id value  but not able to get it using the

```
  select * from EED where id="\\\\1c\\\\04\\\\9c\\\\44\\\\d5\\\\ee\\\\99\\\\44\\\\ad\\\\85\\\\94\\\\6a\\\\e9\\\\7a\\\\69\\\\70"

  select * from EED where id="\\1c\\04\\9c\\44\\d5\\ee\\99\\44\\ad\\85\\94\\6a\\e9\\7a\\69\\70" 

  select * from EED where id like "\\1c\\04\\9c\\44\\d5\\ee\\99\\44\\ad\\85\\94\\6a\\e9\\7a\\69\\70"
```

not able to find using these query.

Comment: Why don't you store binary data using a [binary string type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/binary-varbinary.html), e.g. `VARBINARY(255)` instead of `VARCHAR(255)`?  Then you can avoid hex encoding, and can certainly avoid these superfluous slashes!